# What does the "they" represent?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence

I'm doing TOEFL speaking and noticed that in many conversations, speakers use "they" to represent the school or other institutions. For example, in TPO12's speaking part, the university is planning to expand the range of the school radio station. Here are some of the comments of students:

> Well, if the proposal goes through, there'll be more programs and they'd give the students more professional experience as **they** experiment with programming for a much larger, real-life audience.
>
> He told me that the radio station at his university did something like this about five years ago. Well, it's a success. **They**'re making a lot of money out of commercials.

I'm a bit confused with the two "they." The first "they" refers to the school radio station and the second one refers to the school. So why not use "it" rather than "they?"

Comment: People are involved, aren't they? You know we only use *it* for inanimates, right?

Comment: Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Syntactically speaking, the referent of highlighted ***they*** in the cited text is ***ambiguous*** (it could be preceding ***they*** OR ***the students***). So I think this is Off Topic (it's about logic and/or opinions, not English as such).

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed. For foreign speakers, this is a surprising and interesting aspect, so it is much about _Word choice and usage_
as well as _Grammar_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether to use “they” or “it” in these situations depends on how much distance/intimacy/humanity the speaker wants to express.

In general, if an institution is comprised of people, the speaker would say,“they”. However, it would not be *wrong* to refer to the radio station and the people who run it, as “it”. But “it” would impart a less familiar or connected feeling.

We most frequently use “it” to describe inanimate objects, animals, and beings we don’t care about.

For example, a random dog could be referred to as “it”; but a family pet, or a dog otherwise known to the speaker, could/would be referred to as he or she.

A more uncomfortable use of “it”, (one that would intentionally create/express emotional distance) would be in reference to a human baby/child: “take it away”, “what’s its name?”

Corporation is another example that could be either “it” or “they”. Again, it’s a choice the speaker makes depending on the level of familiarity/humanity they want to impart to what would otherwise represent either a faceless group of people, or an inanimate object/thing.

We might be more inclined to speak of a corporation that does a lot of good for Humanity as “they”. But a profit driven, pollution spewing or disconnected corporation might be referred to as “it”, but it’s not obligatory.

Without regard to emotional nuance, a straight forward formula you could apply to your question is:

Where radio station = *it* — it's more likely referring to just the building or room.

Where radio station = *they* — it's understood that we mean the people who work there.